# How to write $something in a file with sudo tee with bash?

Tags: linux, bash

This is my bash script that write a custom nginx server block aka virtualhost.

```
sudo tee /etc/nginx/sites-available/master <<EOF
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name localhost;
    root        /home/capt/WebRoot;

    location / {
        index       index.php;
        try_files   $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    }

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include                         fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_index                   index.php;
        fastcgi_pass                    unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info         ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO         $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED   $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME   $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
EOF
```

Everything was well written except where there is a $ as in this part:

```
fastcgi_param PATH_INFO         ;
fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED   ;
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME   ;
```

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Easiest way is just to quote `EOF` check my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just quote your `EOF`:

```
sudo tee /etc/nginx/sites-available/master <<'EOF'
```

BTW: anything with `$` should be broken, not just the mentioned lines.

Example:

```
#! /bin/bash

cat <<'EOF'
a=$1
EOF

cat <<EOF
a=$1
EOF
```

Execution:

```
bash test.sh 
a=$1
a=
```

Comment: And if I want to use global variable like $HOME (/home/capt) inside the script?

Comment: Then you need to choose, if you need variable interpolation you need to use unquoted EOF and escape $. Unfortunately you can't have it all

Answer (score 1):

Escape each `$` character with backslash `\`.

So the three lines should look like this:

```
fastcgi_param PATH_INFO         \$fastcgi_path_info;
fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED   \$document_root\$fastcgi_path_info;
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME   \$document_root\$fastcgi_script_name;
```

I guess there is also problem with (at least) `$uri` earlier in the file which you probably missed. So just precisely escape each occurance of `$`.

Comment: Quote `'EOF'` as @Tiago states. His solution looks better.

Answer (score 1):

```
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO         $fastcgi_path_info;
    fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED   $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME   $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
```

Since the words above beginning with `$` are considered variables in bash, and are not yet initialized, they are empty. You should expect exactly the output you get. As provided, escape the `$` with `\$` and you will be fine.